# How to make py.test or nose to look for tests inside all python files?

Tags: python, nose, pytest

I do have several small modules where the tests are inside them and `py.test` or `nose` does not look for them because they do not contain `test` in their filename.

How can I convince `py.test` or `nose` to look for tests inside all python files, recursively - '''including the ones that do not have `test` in their filenames'''?

Inside the source files I do keep the standard naming convention: `class testSomeName` with methods `def test_some_name`.

If this is not possible, what other solution can I use to obtain the same result.

I do not want to manually create a list of all files containing the test, I want a solution that supports discovery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also have a look at [Nose](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/0.11.2/) which will discover tests without having to use a fixed file name convention.

You can bypass the regexp used to filter files in nose with the following code. 
Create a python module (i.e. `my_nosetests.py`)

```
import nose
from nose.plugins.base import Plugin

class ExtensionPlugin(Plugin):

    name = "ExtensionPlugin"

    def options(self, parser, env):
        Plugin.options(self,parser,env)

    def configure(self, options, config):
        Plugin.configure(self, options, config)
        self.enabled = True

    def wantFile(self, file):
        return file.endswith('.py')

    def wantDirectory(self,directory):
        return True

    def wantModule(self,file):
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    includeDirs = ["-w", ".", ".."]
    nose.main(addplugins=[ExtensionPlugin()], argv=sys.argv.extend(includeDirs))
```

Now run `my_nosetests.py` as if you were running `nosetests` and you should have your tests running. Be aware that you are in fact loading all modules and searching for tests in them. Beware of any side effect of module loading.

Comment: With nose you use nosetests in your root directory or pass the directory as an argument. By default it will recurse.

Comment: Rod, probablyyou did not fully read the question, my tests a not inside test*.py files.

Comment: How do I specify a list of directories that I want to include in scanning, by default this example scans in `.` but I want to add other locations like, `../somedir/`. I know that there is the `-w` command line but I would like to be able to include this config option in this file and call it without any parameters.

Comment: I have updated the code to do so. You should be able to go on from that. :)

Comment: I made the same approach, but with one remark, remove the second `-w` from the list. Now nosetest doesn't want several `-w`, it will pick all directories.

Comment: how would I run the tests on executable specifying --exe from with in your code...     ie. nosetests --exe

Answer (score 7):

Put a file "setup.cfg" at the root of project, and it contains this two lines:

```
[pytest]
python_files=*.py
```

then py.test select tests from all `*.py` files.  Here it's explained: [pytest docs](http://pytest.org/latest/example/pythoncollection.html)

with Nose:

```
nosetests --all-modules
```

Comment: I tried this one, and still pytest does not collect anything because of the missing "test_" filename prefix.

Answer (score 5):

With py.test it's simple.  Create a `conftest.py` file with this content:

```
# content of conftest.py file at root of your project
def pytest_collect_file(path, parent):
    if path.ext == ".py":
        return parent.Module(path, parent)
```

This will extend the collection process to create a test "Module" node for each ".py" file. Putting this into a `conftest.py` file makes it a project-specific extension which is automatically loaded if you type:

```
py.test
```

For informational purposes you can also type:

```
py.test --collectonly
```

to see what tests and files are collected, example output:

```
<Directory 'morecollect'>
   <Module 'conftest.py'>
   <Directory 'pkg'>
     <Module 'test_x.py'>
        <Function 'test_hello2'>
   <Module 'x.py'>   # this is collected because of our conftest.py extension
     <Function 'test_hello'>
```

If needed you can also package the above `conftest.py` file as an [installable plugin](http://codespeak.net/py/dist/test/customize.html#writing-setuptools-registered-plugins) and make the extension available by installing the plugin.  In this case you do not need any `conftest.py` file at all.

Comment: For the moment I'm not able to test if this method works because py.test is crashing, see this bug: http://bitbucket.org/hpk42/py-trunk/issue/119/fail-to-impot-__init__py-internalerror

Comment: Hey Sorin.  Ok, Ronny and me just released a new version with a couple of fixes, including the issue you saw. Doing "easy_install -U py" should bring it to you.  Thanks for reporting, have fun. Holger

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://codespeak.net/py/dist/test/customize.html#test-collection-process) says that

> By default all directories not starting with a dot are traversed, looking for test_*.py and *_test.py files. Those Python files are imported under their package name.

Can you ensure that this is the case with your code?

**Update**

(Caveat Emptor: I haven't tried/tested this) How about using the [hooks](http://codespeak.net/py/dist/test/customize.html#generic-collection-hooks) provided for collecting directories and files?

> py.test calls the following two fundamental hooks for collecting files and directories:

```
def pytest_collect_directory(path, parent):
    """ return Collection node or None for the given path. """

def pytest_collect_file(path, parent):
    """ return Collection node or None for the given path. """
```

> Both return a [collection node](http://codespeak.net/py/dist/test/customize.html#collection-node) for a given path. All returned nodes from all hook implementations will participate in the collection and running protocol. The `parent` object is the parent node and may be used to access command line options via the `parent.config` object.

Comment: I did RTFM and exactly this was the problem. I wanted to change this behavior, I do have unittests but they are all embedded in module file and called from __main__. I'm sure that in the future I will want to move them but for the moment I just want to scan for all of them, even in files not using this naming.

Answer (score 0):

For pytest-6 I had to change @hpk42 answer to directly return a Module instance for the given source/test code layout. The original answer raised an exception for this major version of pytest, as the API has changed in the meantime.

```
def pytest_collect_file(path, parent):
    """Look in all Python files for test cases."""
    from _pytest.python import Module

    if path.ext == ".py":
        return Module.from_parent(parent, fspath=path)
```