# Python: Nose is not picking up unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I have written a unit test in python and would like to have it picked up when I run nose. It works fine when I run nose on the file containing the test, i.e.

```
nosetests myFile.py
```

but not when I just run

```
nosetests
```

in the same directory. I thought nose would automatically pick up all tests in the directory where you are running it? Any idea how I can make it work? There are more tests in various files in that directory and I would like to be able to run them at the same time.

This is what my test looks like:

```
class testSimple(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def testStupid(self):
        self.Assert(False)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your test cases python file name should begin with "test" so nose can pick it up.

It is possible to use nose without keeping such naming convetion if you like - required configuration is described in this thread:

[How to make py.test or nose to look for tests inside all python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670515/how-to-make-py-test-or-nose-to-look-for-tests-inside-all-python-files)